# Executing same function every monday at midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, I have this method in my "Aulas" ("Classes" in Portuguese) Controller:

```
def set_week_classes
  classes = Aula.all.to_a
  @this_week_classes = classes.shift(2)
end
```

Considering that "classes" is an array, I would like to have "@this_week_classes = classes.shift(2)" being executed every Monday, at midnight (Brazil's time), getting the next two items of the classes array to be shown on the view. And also, I would like that when it reached the end of the array, it simply started all over, making "@this_week_classes" become again the first two items of the classes array. How could I make this happen? Thank you!

Comment: You do realize that this code will do absolutely nothing for subsequent requests unless you actually update the database table? And its not really like you need it if you actually select the records based on date or use an offset.

Comment: What are you using for production?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Setting an instance variable once a week is pointless because a new controller instance will be created for each request. Instead, try to write a method that returns the desired classes based on the current date.

Comment: BTW, what does `@this_week_classes` represent? From the variable's name I'd expect it to hold the classes for the current week. But having just 2 classes each week doesn't seem to make much sense. I'm just curious, trying to understand the logic behind this :-)

Comment: As for running something regularly, you can use [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). Very simple to set up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sidekiq with some kind of a scheduling gem (like [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) or [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron)). Depending on your installation you could also copy use a [rake task](https://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/) and run it periodically using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If you use cloud then your provider definitely have some kind of scheduler available.

BTW all of your source code should probably be in English. Mixing some  Portuguese class names doesn't look great and can be confusing for other contributors.

But if your only goal is to show some what classes are listed this week it's probably better to do sth like this:

```rb
classes = Aula.all.to_a # not the best for the memory
shift = DateTime.current.weeks_since(CONSTANT_TIME) % classes.size
@this_week_classes = ([classes]+[classes])[shift..(shift+2)] # [classes]+[classes] make sure that we won't get too little classes if we reach the and of the `classes` array
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you ask two questions at the same time:

> 1. Run a job every week at a certain time.

Rails offers different ways to do this. To me the best fit seems to work with an active job library.

Possibilities are:

- https://github.com/javan/whenever cron runner. Let's you set up jobs for every week to run.

Another open library for this type of task is the gem `delayed_job`. It's not very performant but easy to include into small projects.

> 2. Cycle through an array of items.

Here a possibility is instead of actually shifting the items out of your array that you store the job run in your database. Keep in mind there are other possibilities that do not need you to change your database. Following code is not tested but should be seen as pseudocode.

```
def run_job
   last_aula_job = AulaJob.all.order(:created_at).last

   classes = Aula.all.to_a
   total = classes.count
   p = last_aula_job.last_pointer % count
   @this_week_classes = classes[p..p+1]

   # do something with @this_week_classes

   AulaJob.create(last_pointer: p + 2)
end
```

Comment: He doesn't really need to update anything. Just use the week number or something else to calculate a database offset.

Comment: Habit of storing everything... you're right of course.

Comment: I don't know Rails but could you make use of [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle): `classes = Aula.all.to_a.cycle`? For example, `enum = [1,2,3].cycle #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:cycle>; [enum.next, enum.next] #=> [1, 2]; [enum.next, enum.next] #=> [3, 1]`, and so on.